# Tektronix function generator THD

Tags: analog, signal-processing, signal-integrity, function-generator, harmonics

I am confused by the datasheet of the AFG3021C: https://www.tek.com/link-click-count?nid=75006&url=https%3A//download.tek.com/datasheet/AFG3000C-Arbitrary-Function-Generator-Datasheet-75W282817.pdf

I am interested in the THD of a generated sine wave, but the data sheet specifies THD as less then 0.2% and harmonic distortion as <-40 dBc, which just doesn't add up to me.

What is the difference between harmonic distortion and THD? What I am interested in is the RMS of the harmonics divided by the RMS of the fundamental.

Comment: What THD do you need at what  frequency and amplitude ?  THe specs are clear for each range of f with worst case and typical @ 1V

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 They are not clear (at least for me), that is my problem. It very clearly says that the THD is <0.2% (which would be -54 dB (=20*log(0.002)) for the range of 10Hz to 20kHz, but than it also says that the harmonic distortion is <-70dBc, for the same range. So which is it?

Comment: THD is worst case overall but only for audio range ..  Then you have typ and max for each other range

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 But isn't the maximum supposed to be the same as the worst case? The THD is specified from 10Hz to 20kHz '@1Vpp, and the harmonic distortion is specified on this very same interval as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

First I managed to found this: https://download.tek.com/manual/AFG3000C-and-AFG3000-Specifications-and-Performance-Verification-077069102_Rev-B.pdf
Based on this, I got the idea, that the harmonic distortion isn't actually what I (we) though it was at all. It is in fact the level under which all harmonics are supposed to be.

Then I got confirmation from Tektronix:

> The Harmonic Distortion Test specifies that each Harmonic of the
>   Fundamental stays below a certain level in dBc for the corresponding
>   frequency range.
>
> Please note, that if all harmonic components are equal or less than
>   -62 dBm, the THD will be smaller than 0,2%. This value does not directly correlate with the Harmonic Distortion values from the
>   datasheet.

Answer (score 0):

The THD is listed for frequencies up to 20 kHz, whereas the harmonic distortion is given up to higher frequencies. I suspect this is for audio vs RF/analog testing. In the former, people tend to talk about THD, in the case of the latter, they tend to talk about the level of the harmonic with respect to the carried in dBc.

The RMS value of a sine wave is just the peak divided by \$\sqrt{2}\$, so the ratio between the peaks is identical to the ratio between the RMS values.

Comment: You got it right

Comment: OK, but why is the THD spec (0.2% = -54dBc) is different than the harmonic distortion spec for the exact same range (-70dBc) if it is the same thing just under a different name?

Comment: dBc is for sine wave and THD is for arbitrary waves  Square, Pulse, Ramp, Triangle, Sin(x)/x, Exponential Rise and Decay, Gaussian, Lorentz, Haversine, DC, Noise , pulse modulated.  where distortion of spectrum is compared with ideal amplitude and phase

Answer (score 0):

**dBc** is for sine wave and is  -60 dBc for the AFG3011C and -70 dBc for the higher model sampling rates.

Jitter affects dBc on sine carriers with two sidebands each -6dB lower than THD.

Thus -60 dBc = -54 dB THD

e.g.
http://thewelltemperedcomputer.com/Lib/Troisi.pdf

Comment: But the THD spec (and the harmonic distortion spec too) is in the sine wave section, where it talks specifically about sine waves. There are separate sections for the other waveform types: https://imgur.com/MYTdm04